# Vue.js access variable from method

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I try to fetch stocks data from an API. This data should be used to create a chart.js graph.
how do I access in vue.js data to generate a chart.js line chart from the methods http(axios) call?

Is it possible to access the data directly in the mounted component or should I define a const in the  section and create the variables there?

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <div>Selected: {{ selected }}</div>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"  height="200" width="650"></canvas>
  </div>
<script>


export default {
  mounted() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [prices[0].date],
        datasets: [
            {
            label: 'Dataset msft',
            data: prices[0].price
            },
            {
            label: 'Dataset google',
            data: prices[1].price
            },
        ],
      },
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      prices: [],
      options: [
        { text: "msft", value: "msft" },
        { text: "GOOGL", value: "GOOGL" },
      ],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    selected: function () {
      this.getPrice();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPrice: function () {
      var this_ = this;
      axios
        .get(
          "https://site/...."
        )
        .then((response) => {
          // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
          this_.prices = response.data;
        })
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: see: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html load the chart, on mounted grab the data from the api then update the data in the chart, you want to avoid blocking the chart render before fetching the data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access variables in `data()` from `mounted()`.

You need to prepend variables with `this.` when using the Options API

ex: `this.prices[0].price`

Answer (score 1):

As you are putting `watcher` on selected but I did not see any changes in the selected variable in your code. As per my understanding you are making an API call to get the graph data based on the selected option.

If Yes, Instead of generating a chart in mounted you can generate it inside your `getPrice()` method itself based on the response. It should be **:**

```
methods: {
  getPrice: function () {
    var this_ = this;
    axios
      .get(
      "https://site/...."
    )
      .then((response) => {
      this.generateChart(response.data);
    })
  },
    generateChart(prices) {
      const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
      const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: [prices[0].date],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Dataset msft',
              data: prices[0].price
            },
            {
              label: 'Dataset google',
              data: prices[1].price
            }
          ]
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the sample, but the generateChart function does not get executed

Comment: @webdev09 sorry there was a typo. You have to call `this.generateChart(response.data);`

Answer (score 1):

Here, a very basic example:

```
<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick();
    const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [],
      },
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      chart: null,
      options: [
        { text: "msft", value: "msft" },
        { text: "GOOGL", value: "GOOGL" },
      ],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    selected: function () {
      this.getPrice();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async getPrice() {
      let { data } = await axios.get("https://site/....");
      this.chart.data.datasets = [{ label: "dummy data" , data: [2, 3, 4]}];
      this.chart.data.label = [1, 2, 3];
      this.chart.update(); //very important, always update it
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

You create a property called `chart` and save your chart to it.

Then, after you fetch your data, you can access your chart with `this.chart` and then you set your datasets and labels. Whenever you make an change to the chart, use `this.chart.update()` to update it on the browser.

If you execute this code, you should see some dummy data in the chart